# Do default constructor exists with static constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, static-constructor

I am confused with static constructor in a instance class.

As a static constructor is private by default and we can not use access modifier with them, then do default constructor exists with static constructor in a instance class?

If yes, then Why? because we have already defined a constructor(private static and  parameter less) and according to C# concept, if we provide a constructor then the default constructor won't exists. (I might be wrong here)

If No, then Why we are able to create a object of instance class with static constructor.

Below example is complied and executing successfully:

```
public class OOPS
{
    static int i = 0;
     static OOPS(){             
        Console.WriteLine("Static Constructor ");
    }

    //OOPS() {
    //    Console.WriteLine("Instance Constructor");
    //}

    public static void ShowStaticMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("Static Method  ");
    }

    public void ShowInstanceMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("instance Method");
    }
}

class Client
{
    public void ClientMethod() {
        OOPS o = new OOPS();
        o.ShowInstanceMethod();
        OOPS.ShowStaticMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("Client completed");                       
        Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}
```

Comment: The static constructor (a class can only have one) is private because it's called automatically - there's no way to specify parameters or call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if we provide a constructor then the default constructor won't exists.
>   (I might be wrong here)

Well you are wrong about one thing, the above statement is true with respect to **instance constructor**, not static constructor.

Look at the [C# language specification.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

> **10.11.4 Default constructors**
>
> > If a class contains **no instance constructor** declarations, a
> >     default instance constructor is automatically provided.

So, when you provided the static constructor, it didn't have any relation with the default instance constructor, and that is the one you are using later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Static constructor does not affect instance constructors. If you do not want for the class to be instantiated, mark the class as `static`.

```
public static class OOPS
{
   static OOPS()
   {
   }
}
```